# Is there a keyboard shortcut for "save link as" in firefox or chrome?

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys, chromium

I'm tired of right-clicking. Can I do a "Save Link As" by holding a keyboard button and clicking the link?

Comment: I don't know about Ubuntu but on Mac Chrome, Option + Left Click on a link will save the link, which is great when trying to download bank statements :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One solution I found to this, is if you click on the link and open it, you can use

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to save it. It is still slow though.

Answer (score 27):

You can restore the old Alt-click "Save Link As" functionality in Firefox:

Open a new tab in Firefox. In the Firefox **address space**, type:

about:config

Click the "I'll be careful, I promise" prompt.  Type

browser.altClickSave

in the **Search space**.  Double-click on the browser.altClickSave line to change the value from false to true.  Close the about:config tab.

Now when you Alt-click on a valid download link it will open the Save As explorer screen.  All you need to do is set the correct location and press Enter.  Once you set the download location, if you are downloading a lot of files into the same location, all you need to do is press enter.  This will greatly speed up your download process.

I did the above process in Windows 7.  It should also work in Ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work on Debian 9, GNOME, Firefox ESR 60.4.0esr-1~deb9u1. Left-alt+left-click has no effect other than highlighting the link in question. Does not start a download and does not open the "save as" dialog :-(

Comment: It works, see the answer of @yatsek below: press left mouse + press left alt + release left mouse (tested on firefox 74, ubuntu)

Comment: Tested and works with FF 89.0 on OS X (mac). Obviously, you do Option-click. And download happens immediately; no intervening dialog.

Comment: As of Firefox 95 this does not work.  It just straight downloads the file to the default location.  OP asked for SAVE AS which is different.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are correct for Firefox.

For Chrome it's even easier:

Option+Click (Windows: Alt+Click) saves the link-target to the download folder.

Comment: Option?  That's a Mac shortcut.

Comment: @anonymous2 It is equivalent to `alt` on Windows. So `alt + left_click`

Comment: ok, did put the windows-version in the answer now..

Comment: On Windows 10, I had luck with `right Alt + click`.

Comment: @Farhan To "Save As" or just "Save" to the default download folder? None of these answers seems to answer the question of "Save As".

Comment: I've only been able to make Chrome ask to "Save As" if I adjust the "Ask where to save each file before downloading" setting in the Downloads Settings section.

Comment: As of FF 89.0 the Option+Click saves directly to download folder without the "save as" dialog. But you do still have to set 'browser.altClickSave' to True to enable the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux due to the fact that Alt+Click is captured by X11 to manipulate window position to have this working you need quickly:
- Press LMB (and keep pressed)
- Press left Alt key (and keep pressed)
- Release LMB

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for firefox:

K + Right Click

Press K and click with you right mouse button on the link. Release all buttons before the "Download"-Dialog opens up or you will get some K's as the filename.

I can't provide a source as this seems to be an undocumented feature. (Can't see it mentioned [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly) atleast).

Comment: This works because 'k' is the shortcut key in Save Link As... in the right-click menu.  When you hold down 'k', you're spamming the 'k' key, then when you right click, one of those 'k' key spams triggers the shortcut.

Answer (score -1):

Save Linked Page (when a link is selected) (for firefox):

**On Windows :** Shift+Enter

**On Mac :** Option+Enter

**On Linux :** Shift+Enter

([See more shortcuts](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/moz_shortcuts.html))

Comment: Not working for me. I am trying to get this ogg from this site: http://linuxluddites.com/shows/episode-9/ - Shift enter does not work. It just opens it in a new firefox window